# Is there a closed loop in the complex plane such that for any given integer $x$, I can find a point inside the loop that has winding number $x$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, winding-number

We've been discussing winding numbers in my complex course, and also Alexander polynomials and other invariants on knots in my Alg. Top. course, and the question came to me about the possibility of writing down the equation of a curve whose interior takes on every integer value as the winding number.

I believe Stein phrases it like: Given any closed rectifiable curve, for any integer $x$ there is a point $a$ interior to the curve with winding number $x$.

I picture it as an infinitely thick figure "8", because it should loop around itself infinitely many times in both directions, but I'm not actually sure that's possible. Does anybody have any ideas? I've researched some basic complex texts, like Stein or Alfors, but they only mention that such a curve exists, they don't produce one!

Comment: How about a suitably parameterized union of circles $C_n \subset \Bbb R^2$, $n \in \Bbb Z^+$, where $C_n$ is the circle of radius $n^{-2}$ centered at $(n^{-2}, 0)$? Or rather, two copies of this curve, suitably connected, and parameterized in the "opposite" direction, so that one can pick up both positive and negative winding numbers?

Comment: @Travis Hmm, by suitably parametrized, do you mean to find a way to describe them so that they are a closed loop? My concern is that these might not be closed. The circles do intersect each other on the unit interval the way you've described them. It seems like it would be very hard to find a parametrization.

Comment: Parametrize by arc length.

Comment: You can trace out the Hawaiian earring, as Travis says, which takes finite time. If you want the curve to be *immersed* (so the derivative is never zero), then I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @MikeMiller The Hawaiian Earrings look like they would do the job for all positive integers. Looks like I'll have to attach another Hawaiian earring on the opposite side with opposite orientation to get all the negative winding numbers. But I need to find a parametrization of the Hawaiian Earrings to begin with, before I extend it to a double Hawaiian Earring, and I don't find such parametrization readily available online. I'm working on it now.

Comment: @Craig Certainly one can close the loop, and yes, the curve will have to intersect itself (in fact, any closed curve for which there is a point around which it has winding number $\pm 2$ must have a self-intersection). It shouldn't be so hard to write down an explicit parameterization. If one wants to trace just one "earring", one can trace the outermost circle over time $[0, \tfrac{1}{2}]$, the next over $[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}]$, etc.

Comment: Just define the parameterization piecewise, where it's just an (appropriately scaled) parameterization of each circle.

Comment: @MikeMiller The answer below is great, but it's not exactly the Hawaiian rings we were talking about. I'm working on parametrizing the double Hawaiian rings, being exactly circles with centers and radii as described by Travis, and I'm having trouble getting a parametrization for finite time. Did you have anything in mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An explicit parametrization:

$$ \gamma(t) = \cases{\exp(1/t) (1 - \exp(-i/t^2)) & $-1/\sqrt{2\pi} \le t < 0$\cr
0 & $t = 0$\cr
\exp(-1/t) (-1 + \exp(i/t^2)) & $0 < t \le 1/\sqrt{2\pi}$\cr}$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trying to get Mathematica to plot this to make sure I understand how it works!

Comment: For the left side: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Parametric+plot+%28Exp[-1%2Ft]+%28-1+%2B+Cos[1%2Ft^2]%29,+Exp[-1%2Ft]+Sin[1%2Ft^2]%29+for+t+%3D+0+to+1%2FSqrt[2+Pi])

Comment: This looks great. You caught me in the middle of trying to parametrize this, if you have any insight on how you approached this it would be very helpful. I'm still trying to do it for perfect circles, like a double Hawaiian Ring, and my problem is getting the parametrization to be in finite time.